# How can I change the notification sound from parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-broadcast

I've searched a lot on google ,parse.com and stackoverflow.But I really did not find what I need exactly.

I use custom **BroadcastReceiver** for understand the notification came.

But the sound is default sound. Is it possible to change it on android? How can I do this?

(should I do this in parse.com api or can I do this without parse.com api)

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android), you need to recieve the notification using an Intent. You can see [an example of an intent implementation here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), under the "Creating Android Project", item 8.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Quote from the Parse Push Developer Guide:

"For example, to send a notification that would increases the badge number by 1 and plays a custom sound, you can do the following. Note that you can set these properties from your Android client, but they would only take effect in the iOS version of your app. The badge and sound fields would have no effects for Android recipients."

Comment: This are talking about the "sound" and "badge" options in push notifications. When recieving a push in Android, you can treat it inside an intent, and change its sound.